# How to receive more outputs from ODE45

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode45

I have N = 2 coupled nonlinear dynamical systems, whose coupling is give by a 2 by 2 matrix W. Each one of them is described by n = 8 first order ode. The code below, solves this coupled system, for many values of a parameter p:

```
for i=1:length(p)
    [t,y(:,:,i)] = ode45(@(t,y) ode(t,y,n,N,W,p(i,:)), t, y0);
end

function [dydt] = ode(t,y,n,N,W,p)
    dydt = NaN(n, N);
    y = reshape(y,[n, N]);    
    y_out = zeros(N,1);
    F_Global = zeros(N,1);
    for i = 1:N
        y_out(i) = y(3,i)-y(4,i);
    end
    for i = 1:N
        F_Global(i) = W(i,:)*sigm(y_out);
    end
    for i = 1:N
        dydt(1,i) = y(5,i);
        dydt(2,i) = y(6,i);
        dydt(3,i) = y(7,i);
        dydt(4,i) = y(8,i);
        dydt(5,i) = sigm(y(3,i) - y(4,i)) - y(5,i) - y(1,i) + F_Global(i);
        dydt(6,i) = sigm(y(3,i) - y(4,i)) - y(6,i) - y(2,i);
        dydt(7,i) = C2*sigm(y(1,i)) + p(i) - y(7,i) - y(3,i);
        dydt(8,i) = sigm(y(2,i)) - y(8,i) - y(4,i);
    end
    dydt = reshape(dydt,n*N, 1);
end

function X = sigm(u)
    ...
end
```

Within the function, there is already calculated the difference:

```
y_out(i) = y(3,i)-y(4,i);
```

For i = 1,...,N, and for all times, and all values of p, this is supposed to be a 3-D matrix of dimensions

```
y_out = size(length(time), length(p), N);
```

Also, within the function there is calculated the:

```
F_Global(i) = W(i,:)*sigm(y_out);
```

which for i = 1,...,N, and for all values of p, **but after being averaged in time** it is supposed to be a 2-D matrix of dimensions

```
F_Global = size(length(p),N);
```

**I need some help to have y_out and F_Global being extracted as outputs of the ode45**

Comment: Make `y_out` and `F_global` into functions of `y` and evaluate them on the results of the integration. The points where the derivative is evaluated have only a loose relationship with the solution points in the output of ode45, so that the values you could possibly extract from there have little value for further purposes.

Comment: But the `y_out` and `F_Global`, are already functions of `y`. 
How can I evaluate them on the results of the integration? I am not an advanced user, sorry for asking much

Comment: I meant, make them explicitly Matlab functions, so that whenever you need their value, there is one and only one place to get it from and whenever you need to change them, you only need to change one place. // Please explain the connection of the array structure of the output and the array structure that you establish inside the ode function.

Comment: the array structure is demanded from the ode45. If I do not reshape it to an array it gives error. I am trying making them explicit Matlab functions

Comment: Yes, that is clear. With the standard function you have to use wrapper functions to transform from model representation to flat array and back. The question is, in the return value you take the sequence of flat arrays and store it in a 3D structure. So essentially what you get is a 4D model stored in 3D, with indices for time, the flattened nxN model and the parameter index. Is that as you intended it?

Comment: You could also add components to the state whose derivative is `F_global` so that averaging `F_global` then only requires dividing by the total time of the integrals computed in these components. The transformation to a flat array and back then becomes a little bit more involved, and should be done perhaps in dedicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

Changed code

```
output_potential = NaN(length(time),N,length(p));
Sigm = NaN(N,length(p));
input_firingRate = NaN(N,length(p));

for i=1:length(p)
    [t,y(:,:,i)] = ode45(@(t,y) ode(t,y,n,N,W,p(:,i)), time, y0);
    for j = 1:N
        output_potential(:,j,i) = y(:,3+(j-1)*n,i) - y(:,4+(j-1)*n,i);
        Sigm(j,i) = sigm(mean(output_potential(:,j,i)));
    end
    input_firingRate(:,i) = p(:,i) + A*a*W(:,:)*Sigm(:,i);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have some queries:
1. what does the `y0(:,p)` mean?
2. I chose to include a for-loop within the `ode` function, because the system is coupled. If the number of coupled system was for example N = 190, which is something that has to happen eventually, it would be prohibitive to write down all these equations.

Comment: you mean that 

    `yout = y(:,3:8:end,:) - y(:,4:8:end,:);`

    `WW = repmat(W(:)',[size(y,1) 1 size(y,3)]);`

    `F_global = WW .* yout;`

has to be placed outside of the for loop, exactly as you have written it?

Comment: Yes, after you get all results

Comment: I am getting an error:

Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

`Error in test3 (line 27)`
    `F_global = WW .* yout;`

Comment: Is size of **W** 1xN?

Comment: No, neither the W, nor the WW. 
If I understand well, you are suggesting, instead of having the `ode` produce more outputs, that the calculation be done after the completion of the integration. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, i want to obtain `F_global` and `yout` after calculation/integration completed. I made some correction, please try

Comment: `Matrix dimensions must agree.`

`Error in test2 (line 35)
            FF(k1,k2) = sum(yout(k1,:).*W(k2,:));`

I am editing something in your code, above. I would appreciate your opinion. The initial goal though was to have `F_Global` and `y_out` directly coming as outputs out of the function `ode` without having to re-calculate everything after the integration

Comment: Try to change the line: `yout = y1(:,3:8:end) - y1(:,4:8:end);`